# why arent item tags not respected in json deserialization

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have implemented a custom crafting block and recipe type in my mod.  For one of these recipes, I want it to accept any type of leaves as input.  However, when I check the logs for the printout of the deserialized json recipes, the tag has been replaced with a barrier. I am using Ingredient.fromJson() to deserialize.  This does not affect single items (eg the printout says the ingredients are one water_bucket and one barrier).  Any idea why?

tea.json:

```json
{
  "type": "naturesway:brewery",
  "ingredients": [
    { "item": "minecraft:water_bucket" },
    { "tag": "minecraft:leaves" }
  ],
  "result": {
    "item": "naturesway:tea",
    "count": 1
  }
}
```